# Join() an array by tab?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to integrate with a legacy system which depends on a value being sent via a GET request as a tab delimited string. I have my data in an array, but am having an issue trying to `join()` it in the correct manner.

Here's is what I've attempted, none of which works;

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

myArray.join(\t);
myArray.join(/\t/);
myArray.join('\t');
myArray.join('\\t');
myArray.join('   '); // tab character
```

**Edit**

It appears the actual issue appears that joining by `\t` does indeed work, however when it is URL encoded the tab is not being turned into `%09` as it should be, but is instead removed.

Desired URL encoded var:

```
"?tags=a%09b%09c"
```

Actual output:

```
"?tags=abc"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: How do you show the output? maybe you just need `&emsp;`? And what's wrong with: `myArray.join('   ');`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one works on my chrome console :

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

console.log(myArray.join('\t'));
```

See on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGZdk/1/).

This one is working too :

```
myArray.join('   '); // tab character
```

Browser : Chrome 26.0.1410.65 (os x)

**Edit** :

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

var string = myArray.join('\t');

var url = encodeURIComponent(string);

console.log(url); //output : a%09b%09c
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mGZdk/2/

Comment: I can confirm on Chrome 26 on Linux.

Comment: +1 For your answer, however it does not completely solve my issue. I've added more detail to my question.

Comment: edited and it's working fine on my browser (watch the console).

Comment: `encodeURIComponent`! Of course! I completely forgot that and left it to the browser to encode - stupid idea. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you aren't assigning it to a new variable. Join() does not modify the original variable. Try this:

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

var array_string = myArray.join('\t');

alert(array_string);
```

Comment: I realise that, it was only how I simplified the question. The actual code does is not formatted in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

`\t` should work...

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var str = arr.join("\t");
```

However, how are you displaying your output? If you are trying to display the content on a normal HTML page, the tabs will appear like spaces. If you put the contents in special elements like `<pre>`, they should appear normally.

I know it's a nasty solution, but you can use multiple `&nbsp;` instead...

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var str = arr.join("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"); // s-sorry ;__;
```